# How to Interpret BR LC3 assembly formats

Tags: assembly, encoding, lc3

I am currently looking at an appendix for LC3 assembly instructions to determine how interpret the encoding the instruction BRNP THERE for part of an assignment. The description for Break that the appendix gives me raises the following questions.

This the psuedocode I was given:

```
        .
        .
        .
        ADD R3, R5    ;x3004
        BRNP LABEL    ;x3005
LABEL     .fill 43    ;x3006
.end
```

How can both of the N and P bits be set and what effect does that have on the PC after the operation is executed?

Is the encoding for the instruction at address x3005 the following:

```
        000   101   000000001
bits:  15-12  11-9     8-0
```

I was not able to find any related documentation for the BR instruction on the site. Thank you for the help in advance.

Comment: `NP` is missing the `Z`, so that effectively means "not zero". We can't tell the effect because we don't know the content of `R3` and `R5` so can't tell what the result will be. In the given code execution continues to `LABEL` anyway because it's the next instruction, so it doesn't matter.

Comment: As for the encoding, note that `15-12` is 4 bits, and also that address is relative to the next instruction (normal control flow) so the offset would be `0` not `1`. You can always check the machine code using your assembler.